# How does Constructor DI work using AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor?

Tags: spring, annotations

According to the Spring Framework JavaDoc, the `BeanPostProcessor` is a:

> Factory hook that allows for custom modification of new bean instances

Does Spring instantiate non-lazy singleton beans via `preInstantiateSingletons` using reflection and then later the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` uses reflection to set fields (such as final fields) that have `@Autowired` defined on the constructor (and setter / fields)?

If so, is it possible to write a custom `BeanPostProcessor` that processes before the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to verify this behavior? I have tried doing this with a custom `BeanPostProcessor` by implementing `PriorityOrdered` as follows:

```
@Override
public int getOrder() {
    return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
}
```

Note: However, when `postProcessBeforeInitialization` is called, beans appear to already have fields set via `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 1):

look inside **AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean**.
there are three steps basically.

1. **createBeanInstance** construct bean object
2. **populateBean**  autowired bean property values
3. **initializeBean** fire BeanPostProcessor

so **BeanPostProcessor** is too late.but look inside **populateBean**,you will find **InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor** will execute before autowired property.
so you can create bean type of **InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor** for you purpose.

**full example**

```
@Configuration
public class DIBeforeAutowired {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.register(DIBeforeAutowired.class);
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.refresh();
        InjectClass injectClass = annotationConfigApplicationContext.getBean(InjectClass.class);
        injectClass.print();
    }

    @Component
    public static class InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorTest extends AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor {

        public boolean postProcessAfterInstantiation(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof InjectClass) {
                System.out.println(((InjectClass) bean).getInjectField());
            }
            return true;
        }

        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof InjectClass) {
                System.out.println(((InjectClass) bean).getInjectField());
            }
            return bean;
        }

        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof InjectClass) {
                System.out.println(((InjectClass) bean).getInjectField());
            }
            return bean;
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class InjectField {
        public String getHelloWorld() {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class InjectClass {

        @Autowired
        InjectField injectField;

        public void print() {
            System.out.println(injectField.getHelloWorld());
        }

        public InjectField getInjectField() {
            return injectField;
        }

    }

}
```